# Split contents of column into two rows, for conversion to STRUCTURE format

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to separate the contents of columns into two rows, and duplicate the row names.  Each variable consists of only two numbers (11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, etc. or an NA.)  This is for conversion to STRUCTURE format, a common population genetics format.

I have this:

```
population      X354045  X430045   X995019
Crater          <NA>     11        22
Teton           11       31        11
```

I would like to have this:

```
population      X354045  X430045   X995019
Crater          <NA>     1         2
Crater          <NA>     1         2
Teton           1        3         1
Teton           1        1         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `data.table` question, so I would just suggest the built-in `tstrsplit` function for that matter

*Reading Your data*

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('population      X354045  X430045   X995019
Crater          NA     11        22
                 Teton           11       31        11')
```

*Solution* (if you have a `data.frame`, use `setDT(DT)` in order to convert to a `data.table`)

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ""))), by = population]
#    population X354045 X430045 X995019
# 1:     Crater      NA       1       2
# 2:     Crater      NA       1       2
# 3:      Teton       1       3       1
# 4:      Teton       1       1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is how I would do it. Lets create some data:

```
vector <- c(10, 11, 12, NA, 13, 14, 15)
```

First, we need a function that allows you to break each two-digit number into its two digits (and NAs into two NAs):

```
as.numeric(sapply(vector, function(x) (x %% c(1e2,1e1)) %/% c(1e1,1e0)))
# 1  0  1  1  1  2 NA NA  1  3  1  4  1  5
```

Now all we have to do is apply this to every relevant column:

```
DF <- data.frame(population = c("Crater", "Teton"), X354045 = c(NA, 11), X430045 = c(11, 31), X995019 = c(22, 11))
DF2 <- apply(DF[-1], 2, function(y) as.numeric(sapply(y, function(x) (x %% c(1e2,1e1)) %/% c(1e1,1e0))))
```

Finally, we just combine it with the new population column:

```
population <- as.character(rep(DF$population, each = 2))
DF3 <- cbind(population, data.frame(DF2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'population      X354045  X430045   X995019
Crater          NA     11        22
Teton           11       31        11')

nr <- nrow(dd)
dd <- dd[rep(1:2, each = nr), ]

#     population X354045 X430045 X995019
# 1       Crater      NA      11      22
# 1.1     Crater      NA      11      22
# 2        Teton      11      31      11
# 2.1      Teton      11      31      11


dd[, -1] <- lapply(dd[, -1], function(x) {
  idx <- (seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0) + 1L
  substr(x, idx, idx)
})

#     population X354045 X430045 X995019
# 1       Crater    <NA>       1       2
# 1.1     Crater    <NA>       1       2
# 2        Teton       1       3       1
# 2.1      Teton       1       1       1
```

Or just

```
dd <- dd[rep(1:2, each = nr), ]
dd[, -1] <- lapply(dd[, -1], function(x)
  Vectorize(substr)(x, rep(1:2, nr), rep(1:2, nr)))
```

would work

---

And the same idea in `data.table` thanks to @DavidArenburg

```
library('data.table')
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'population      X354045  X430045   X995019
    Crater          NA     11        22
                 Teton           11       31        11')


setDT(dd)[rep(1:2, each = .N), lapply(.SD, substr, 1:2, 1:2), by = population]

#    population X354045 X430045 X995019
# 1:     Crater      NA       1       2
# 2:     Crater      NA       1       2
# 3:      Teton       1       3       1
# 4:      Teton       1       1       1
```

Or similarly, but avoiding the `by` part

```
dd <- setDT(dd)[rep(1:2, each = .N)]
dd[, 2:4 := dd[ ,lapply(.SD, substr, 1:2, 1:2), .SD = -1]]
```

which should be pretty fast/efficient if you are working with a large data set

Comment: thanks @DavidArenburg updated, now everyone will think I'm using data table!